# Bootstrap carousel with Javascript function to play and pause (JQUERY)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I pass the course, I did everything according to the video and instructions, but then there was a problem that when you click on the button ( pause symbol), it does not change to play symbol. But there is block is working

[image]

What should I do?

Javascript/CSS/HTML

```js
<script>
   
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#carousel').carousel( { interval: 2000 } );
    $("#carouselButton").click(function(){
                if ($("#carouselButton").children("span").hasClass('fa-pause')) {
                    $("#carousel").carousel('pause');
                    $("#carouselButton").children("span").removeClass('fa-pause');
                    $("#carouselButton").children("span").addClass('fa-play');
                }
                else if ($("#carouselButton").children("span").hasClass('fa-play')){
                    $("#carousel").carousel('cycle');
                    $("#carouselButton").children("span").removeClass('fa-play');
                    $("#carouselButton").children("span").addClass('fa-pause');                    
                }
            });
    });
</script>
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #FAEBD7
}
.jumbotron {
    padding:70px 30px 70px 30px;
    margin:0px auto;
    background: #8A2BE2 ;
    color:floralwhite;

}
.navbar-inner {
    background:transparent;
}
.main-info{
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.mgleft {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.about {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-left: 120px;
}
.row-header {
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 1px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
/*class for separating the two forms which stick together*/
.form {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.row-content {
    margin:0px auto;
    padding: 50px 0px 50px 0px;
    border-bottom: 1px ridge;
    min-height:400px;
}
.corporate {
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 50px
}

.footer{
    background-color: #D1C4E9;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
}
.Meet {
    margin-bottom: 100px
}
.tab-content {
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding: 10px;
}
.carousel {
    background:#512DA8;
}

.carousel-item {
  height: 300px;
}

.carousel-item img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    min-height: 300px;
}
.bottom-reserve{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#carouselButton {
    right: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
HTML
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <title>Ristorante Con Fusion: About Us</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap-social/bootstrap-social.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    
</head>


<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-sm fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Navbar">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand mr-auto" href="./index.html"><img src="/pictures/logo.png" height="30" width="41" ></a>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Navbar">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="./index.html"><span class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></span> Home</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="./aboutus.html"><span class="fa fa-info fa-lg"></span> About</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="fa fa-list fa-lg"></span> Menu</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item "><a class="nav-link" href="#"><span class="fa fa-address-card fa-lg"></span> Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                <span class="navbar-text">
                    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login">
                        <span class="fa fa-sign-in"></span> Log-in
                    </a>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div id="login" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="content">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title" data-html="true"><strong>Login </h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                                    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail3">Email address</label>
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-sm mr-1" id="exampleInputEmail3" placeholder="Enter email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                                <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword3">Password</label>
                                <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-sm mr-1" id="exampleInputPassword3" placeholder="Password">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-auto">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox">
                                    <label class="form-check-label"> Remember me
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm ml-auto" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ml-1">Sign in</button>        
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="reservemodal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-md" role="content">
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title" data-html="true">Reserve a Table </h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <label for="Number" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Number of Guests</label>
                            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">1</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">2</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">3</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">4</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">5</label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">6</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                            <!-- Number of Guests end -->
                            
                        <div class="form-row">    
                            <label for="Number" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Section</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
                                    <label class="btn btn-success btn-sm active">
                                        <input type="radio" name="options" id="non-smoking" autocomplete="off" checked> Non-smoking
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                                        <input type="radio" name="options" id="smoking" autocomplete="off"> Smoking
                                    </label>  
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <label for="Number" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Date and time</label>
                            <div class="form-row col">
                                <div class="col">
                                    <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" placeholder="Date">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col">
                                    <input type="time" class="form-control" placeholder="Time">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                            

                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row col-md-6 bottom-reserve">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm ml-auto" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ml-1">Reserve</button>        
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <header class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-5">
                    <h1>Ristorante con Fusion</h1>
                    <p>We take inspiration from the World's best cuisines, and create a unique fusion experience. Our lipsmacking creations will tickle your culinary senses!</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-3 align-self-center">
                    <img src="/pictures/logo.png" class="img-fluid">
                </div>
                <div class="button-group col-12 col-sm-3 col-md">
                    <a role="button" class="btn btn-warning nav-link btn-lg" href="#top" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reservemodal">Reserve a Table</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row row-content">
            <div class="col">
                <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="/pictures/uthappizza.png" alt="uthapizza">
                            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                <h2 class="mt-0">Uthappizza <span class="badge badge-danger">HOT</span> <span class="badge badge-secondary">$4.99</span> </h2>

                                <p class="d-none d-sm-block">A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and
                                Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine
                                cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and
                                Buffalo Paneer.</p>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="/pictures/buffet.png" alt="buffet">
                            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                <h2 class="mt-0">Weekend Grand Buffet <span class="badge badge-danger">NEW</span> </h2>

                                <p class="d-none d-sm-block">Featuring mouthwatering combinations with a choice of live five different salads, six enticing appetizers, six main entrees and five choicesst desserts. Free flowing bubbly and soft drinks. All for just $19.99 per person.</p>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="/pictures/alberto.png" alt="alberto">
                            <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                <h2 class="mt-0">Albero Somayya <span class="badge badge-danger">HOT</span> </h2>
                                <h3 classs="mt-0">Executive Chef</h3>

                                <p class="d-none d-sm-block">Award winning three-star Michelin with wide International experience having worked closely with whos-who in the culinary workld, he specializes in creating mouthwatering Indo-Italian fusion experiences.</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    </ol>
                    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="btn group" id="carouselButton">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="carouselButton">
                        <span id="carousel-button-icon" class="fa fa-pause"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">

            
            <div class="col-12 "> <!-- col-sm-12 col-lg-9 -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 order-sm-last col-md-2">
                        <h3>Our Lipsmaking Culinary Creations</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="media main-info col-8">
                        <img class="d-flex mr-3 img-thumbnail align-self-center" src="/pictures/uthappizza.png" alt="Uthappizza">
                        <div class="media-body col-12">
                            <h2 class="mt-0">Uthappizza <span class="badge badge-danger">HOT</span> <span class="badge badge-secondary">$4.99</span> </h2>

                            <p class="d-none d-sm-block">A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and
                                Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine
                                cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and
                                Buffalo Paneer.</p>
                        </div>
                 </div>

                <!--  <div class="col-4">
                    <h1>Our Lipsmacking Culinary Creations</h1>
                </div> -->
            </div>
        </div>
            <div class="row main-info">
                <!-- <div class="media col-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                    <h3>This Month's Promotions</h3>
                </div> -->
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 col-md-2 order-sm-first">
                    <h3>This Month's Promotions</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col col-sm col-md-9">
                    <img class="d-flex mr-3 img-thumbnail rounded float-right" src="/pictures/buffet.png" alt="Grand Buffet">
                    <div class="media-body">
                        <h2 class="mt-0">Weekend Grand Buffet <span class="badge badge-danger">NEW</span> </h2>

                        <p class="d-none d-sm-block">Featuring mouthwatering combinations with a choice of live five different salads, six enticing appetizers, six main entrees and five choicesst desserts. Free flowing bubbly and soft drinks. All for just $19.99 per person.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        
            <div class="row">
                <div class="media main-info">
                    <!-- <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 order-sm-last col-md-2">
                        <h3>Meet Our Culinary Specialists</h3>
                    </div> -->
                    <img class="d-flex mr-3 img-thumbnail rounded float-left" src="/pictures/alberto.png" alt="boss">
                    <div class="media-body col-8">
                         <h2 class="mt-0">Albero Somayya <span class="badge badge-danger">HOT</span> </h2>
                         <h3 classs="mt-0">Executive Chef</h3>

                        <p class="d-none d-sm-block">Award winning three-star Michelin with wide International experience having worked closely with whos-who in the culinary workld, he specializes in creating mouthwatering Indo-Italian fusion experiences.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>   
                    
            </div>
        </div>
    

        

        <div class="row row-content">

            <div class="card">
                <h5 class="card-header bg-warning" id="top">Reserve a Table</h5>
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Number" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Number of Guests</label>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio1" value="option1">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">1</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">2</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">3</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">4</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">5</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptions" id="inlineRadio2" value="option2">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">6</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                            <!-- Date and Time -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Number" class="col-md-3 col-form-label">Date and time</label>
                        <div class="form-row col">
                            <div class="col">
                                <input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" placeholder="Date">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                <input type="time" class="form-control" placeholder="Time">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class=" mgleft btn btn-primary">Reserve</button>    
                </form>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">             
                <div class="col-4 offset-1 col-sm-2">
                    <h5>Links</h5>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-7 col-sm-5">
                    <h5>Our Address</h5>
                    <address>
                        121, Clear Water Bay Road<br>
                        Clear Water Bay, Kowloon<br>
                        HONG KONG<br>
                        <i class="fa fa-phone fa-lg"></i>: +852 1234 5678<br>
                        <i class="fa fa-fax fa-lg"></i>: +852 8765 4321<br>
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-lg"></i>: 
                        <a href="mailto:confusion@food.net">confusion@food.net</a>
                    </address>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 align-self-center">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-google" href="http://google.com/+"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id="><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-linkedin" href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-twitter" href="http://twitter.com/"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-social-icon btn-google" href="http://youtube.com/"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-social-icon" href="mailto:"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-center">             
                <div class="col-auto">
                    <p>© Copyright 2018 Ristorante Con Fusion</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    
    

    
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS. -->
    <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    
<script>
   
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#carousel').carousel( { interval: 2000 } );
    $("#carouselButton").click(function(){
                if ($("#carouselButton").children("span").hasClass('fa-pause')) {
                    $("#carousel").carousel('pause');
                    $("#carouselButton").children("span").removeClass('fa-pause');
                    $("#carouselButton").children("span").addClass('fa-play');
                }
                else if ($("#carouselButton").children("span").hasClass('fa-play')){
                    $("#carousel").carousel('cycle');
                    $("#carouselButton").children("span").removeClass('fa-play');
                    $("#carouselButton").children("span").addClass('fa-pause');                    
                }
            });
    });
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: $ is not defined" means that you didn't include the jQuery library source code link in a script tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You accidently used `"crousalButton"` Id Twice. Remove first reference.
Here:

```
                <div class="btn group" id="carouselButton">
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="carouselButton">
                    <span id="carousel-button-icon" class="fa fa-pause"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
```

**make it:**

```
<div class="btn group" >
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" id="carouselButton">
                    <span id="carousel-button-icon" class="fa fa-pause"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
```

Comment: I will edit your question to make it more helpful for others.